# PowerBI - Summarize by Day and Count IF

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a bunch of daily transactions where I would like to be able to look at all of the transactions for a given day and if the PAST_DUE column = 1 then I count it else I don't.

Here is the calculated column I have been working on that is not producing the correct number.

```
Lines = 
VAR RowDate = opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT(opr_shipments[Orders]),
        FILTER (
            opr_shipments,
            opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] <= RowDate
                && DAY ( opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] ) = DAY ( RowDate )
        ), FILTER(opr_shipments, opr_shipments[PAST_DUE] = 1)
    )
```

I am pretty sure I am not doing the daily grouping correctly, I do have a Calendar table I can link to, just not sure what that function should look like.

**My Table:**
[image]

**Calendar Table:**
[image]

**Orders Table**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your calendar table looks like so I created one from the shipment date using:

```
Calendar = CALENDAR(MIN(opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE]), MAX(opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE]))
```

No particular relationship is needed between the tables.

[image: tables]

Then the total number of orders is calculated by:

```
TotalOrders = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(opr_shipments[Orders]),
    FILTER(
        opr_shipments,
        opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] = 'Calendar'[Date] &&
        opr_shipments[PAST_DUE] = 1
    )
) + 0
```

And the result will be as follows:

[image: result]

P.S. Not sure what calculation you're doing, in case you want to switch the `COUNT(opr_shipments[Orders])` with `SUM(opr_shipments[Orders])` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated my question with images of my tables. When I implement your solution I am getting the following error:  single value for column 'Date' in table 'calendar' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx Which exact step did you get this error? Did you try my `Calendar` expression to create a `Calculated Table` (not `Column`)?

Comment: I used the formula you submitted as a new calculated column called LateLines. I already have a date table called calendar so didnt have to do anything there.

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx Can you try using the Calendar expression then? Because there seems some problems with your date table. And the LateLines column should be created in the date table, not the opr_shipments table. Is it the case?